# Certain PNG Drawable causes crash on HoneyComb

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I am using an Icon Pack [Specifically This One.](http://www.magetemplates.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=38%3afreebies-free-android-mega-pack-110-icons-17-android-emoticons&catid=9%3afreebies&Itemid=12)

I use about 4 icons so far. My app works great on my Evo 3d and on the emulator. So when I tried to put it on my HoneyComb 3.2 tablet I was surprised when it wouldn't run. I narrowed it down to one drawable. Changing the drawable's XML to utilize another PNG, the app runs fine. I have tried reimporting the resource but it hasn't worked.  The error it throws is an InflateException. Any Activity that uses the drawable will crash. It has me perplexed. Is there anything I can double check?

Like I said, It runs fine on 2.3.7 on my evo 3d, and 2.3.1 on the emulator. Just on 3.2 it will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ii might be because of the size of PNG's. It has happened to me sometime that when size of images is big then app crashes giving a similar exception.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth posting some sample code and stacktraces if you have any. I'd be happy to try the example on my galaxy nexus (running 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right size. The size of an hdpi icon corresponding to a mdpi icon is to multiply by 1.5 the dimensions (because resolution is 1.5 times greater: 240dpi vs 160dpi). Remember tablets are xlarge screens with mdpi.